# Dice game wont break loop

Tags: python

A loop keeps breaking with the == or is function even though it should continue so the player gets another go at rolling. I cant find out why so can someone please help me. That would be great.

```
elif roll1 is roll2:
        print(score1)
        continue
```

or

```
elif roll1 == roll2:
        print(score1)
        continue
```

neither of them work so does anyone know why.

```
 while True:
    print(" ")
    input("Press enter to roll player 1 ")
    print("Rolling dice!")
    roll1=random.randint(1,6)
    roll2=random.randint(1,6)
    print(roll1)
    print(roll2)
    total=(roll1 + roll2)
    print("Your total is:" ,total)
    score1=score1 +total
    even = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
    odd = [3,5,7,9,11]

    if total in even:
        score1=score1 +10
        print(score1)
        break
    elif total in odd:
        score1=score1 -5
        print(score1)
        break
    elif roll1 == roll2:
        print(score1)
        continue
```

There is the full loop

Comment: please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you please include the full code with the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
if total in even:
    score1=score1 +10
    print(score1)
    break
elif total in odd:
    score1=score1 -5
    print(score1)
    break
elif roll1 == roll2:
    print(score1)
    continue
```

you will never reach the last elif, since total is always in `even` or `odd`.  If you want the reroll first, you should move up the elif to something like this:

```
if roll1 == roll2:
    print(score1)
    continue
elif total in odd:
    score1=score1 -5
    print(score1)
    break
elif total in even:
    score1=score1 +10
    print(score1)
    break
```